# ionic 5 using local file when offline for tranlation

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, translation, ionic5, ngx-translate

I am having a ionic 5 app where i am using translation with

```
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
```

and I load it like:

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, "https://XXX" + "/assets/i18n/", ".json");
}
```

And I have different language files here. We recently started supporting the app in the offline mode in which case the HTTP URL won't be available. So, how do I deal with that case as I would like to show the English version at least when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `@ngx-translate`, your `app.module.ts` should look like

```
import ...
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient): TranslateHttpLoader {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        ...
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        })
    ],
    providers: [
        ...
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The module of any page component which uses translation should look like

```
import ...
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,
    TranslateModule
  ],
  declarations: [SomePage]
})
export class SomePageModule {}
```

Offline translation should be fine.

You may take my [Ionic app project](https://github.com/tomfong/simple-qr) as reference, in which multiple languages are supported.

**Edit 1:**

If you have to check condition, e.g. network, before picking translate loader, a custom `TranslateHttpLoader` might help you.

The class should look like

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { TranslateLoader } from "@ngx-translate/core";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export class TranslateHttpLoader implements TranslateLoader {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, public prefix: string, public suffix: string) 
  {
    // Your logic
  }

  public getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<Object> {
    if (Your logic)
      return this.http.get(`${local_path}`);
    else
      return this.http.get(`${online_path}`);
  }
}
```

Then in `app.module.ts`, import it

```
TranslateModule.forRoot({
  loader: {
    provide: TranslateLoader,
    useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory, // <-- Here
    deps: [HttpClient]
  }
})
```

Comment: well you have replaced the http url with the local translation file. that is not what i want, i need to make that happen only when there is no network else it should pick the translation file from the https. so need to check and switch somehow

Comment: @MoblizeIT Please check my edit.